# What outlier detection methods I could use based on learning from input to response relations?

Tags: outliers, anomaly-detection

There are few factors affecting the response variable in my data. There could be a bigger numerical response value and it might not be an outlier because of 'valid' factors. The outlier is basically the one which produces a bigger response while the rest the of the data doesn't when given the similar factors.
So the outlier definition depends on the input variables (factors) to response relation. Which outlier detection methods I could use to detect multiple outliers from existing data.

Comment: Some combination of imagined constraints on the population and anomalies in the data could lead to almost any 'outlier'-detection rule. Perhaps choose a maximum realistic population value, then look for extreme data values using (a) 95th or 99th sample quantiles and/or boxplot 1.5 IQR rule. Then examine each outlier in context to try to separate the unanticipated and the rare from the impossible and wrong. // Deleting outliers without iron-clad rules for determining actual errors (data entry, eqpt failure, etc.) is always risky and often counterproductive.

Comment: I am actually not removing the outliers from the data, in my case, the outlier data points have some business value. Anyway I understand what you mean. Thanks.